# Generate odds ratios across deciles / quantiles of an indpendent variable

Tags: logistic, odds-ratio, odds, logistic-curve, sigmoid-curve

With reference to the following figure from [Bellomo et al., 2011](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/50347572_Arterial_hyperoxia_and_in-hospital_mortality_after_resuscitation_from_cardiac_arrest):

[image]

How exactly are the odds ratios across the deciles 'referenced against the 4th decile' calculated?

My initial impression is that a logistic model is constructed as such:

```
binary_outcome ~ 10_deciles_dummy_matrix + covariates + intercept
```

Where `binary_outcome` is a `Nx1` vector of `N` samples, `10_deciles_dummy_matrix` is a `Nx10` matrix, and `intercept` is a `Nx1` vector of 1s, `covariates` is a `NxM` matrix of M covariates.

Perhaps plotted in the figure is the coefficient (beta value) for each of the columns in the `10_deciles_dummy_matrix` divided by the coefficient of the fourth decile (because they're referenced against the 4th decile).

However, the problem with such a model is that there is perfefct colinearity between `10_deciles_dummy_matrix` and `intercept`. Also how would the standard errors scale given division of coefficient values with the 4th decile?

Since removing the intercept isn't an option, alternatively we can remove a decile (or a column) from `10_deciles_dummy_matrix`, but then we are left with a missing decile in our plot (which can't be the fourt decile since we need something to reference against).

Leading to my question, what is the statistical procedure that has been performed to generate the above figure?

Comment: Full reference please. You know it, so please show it, and cut out many searches for it by others.

Answer (score 1):

PaO2 is a measure of pulmonary function. We are to assume whatever the outcome is here, it's bad, as very low PaO2 has a higher odds of *something*.

The study team has applied some bad statistical practices here: dividing up a strong predictor into an arbitrary number of percentiles and using odds ratios rather than risk ratios to summarize associations in what we must assume is a prospective study.

When fitting a categorical predictor, one category is chosen as a reference. The odds ratio summarizes association by taking the odds of an outcome for any of the other 9 categories versus a reference. Categorical predictors require a reference for dummy variable encoding by default.

They have chosen PaO2 range 83-93 as the "reference". When you calculate a predictor matrix, you drop indicators of membership to this group. The interpretation of the intercept is the odds of this "bad" outcome given your PaO2 is 83-93 (whatever the units are). Notice on the plot there is no bar for this category.

The odds ratios and their 95% CIs are estimated from logistic regression. "Adjusted" further includes (what we must assume) as possible confounders of association.

Comment: Not my field, but a quadratic in log PaO2 might yield a better model. (As you say, why bin a continuous predictor, especially when functional dependence seems to have a fairly simple shape?)

Comment: @NickCox or use a spline!

Comment: Sure. I let other people suggest splines. I would always use something simpler without knots if it worked as well, or even slightly worse.